# What happens to your voicemail greeting when you "erase all contents and settings?"

Tags: iphone, voicemail

I've run into an interesting scenario that hadn't crossed my mind before.  One of our employees is preparing to leave the organization.  She will be turning in her iPhone and is requesting that we remove all of the data from it.  Not a problem, Settings > General > Reset > Erase all Contents & Settings will do the trick.

However, she has recommended that we leave a voicemail greeting (the clip people hear when they reach your voicemail) with a notice that the caller should call our main number rather than wait on a response from her phone number.  This makes sense, but I'm not sure if that greeting will be wiped as well when we clear her phone.

I suspect that the greeting is stored on the carrier's end, rather than locally on the iPhone, but I'd like to check first.  Does anyone know for sure?

Answer (score 1):

Make back up.

Scan your Mac to locate iPhone backups. Then locate the voicemail greeting by going to this location:

```
System Files/Home Domain/Library/Voicemail
```

Inside the Voicemail folder locate the greeting.amr file. Select it and click the Export button to save a copy on your Mac’s Desktop. Double-click this file to listen to it to make sure it’s the file you want to retrieve. If so, you’re now ready to restore this file to your iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the outgoing voicemail message is stored in the carriers network .... If you take the SIM card out of a phone (as long as you keep paying the bill) the voicemail message doesn't disappear, so I can't see why you can't reset all the settings on the phone.... the only variation to this may be if you are using visual voicemail (but I am not sure any carrier still supports this).

Comment: Visual voicemail seems to be how the Voicemail tab in the Phone app works, so it's definitely still around. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201436